# Gesture recognizer doens't work on UICollectionViewCell inside of other UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I created `UICollectionView` as major UI and each `collectionViewCell` take a whole screen and it's horizontally scrolled with paging.
Things are going ok until I have to implement another `UICollectionView` inside of parent `CollectionViewCell`.

So.. scrolling gesture could be either scrolling the parent collectionView or could also be scrolling small collectionView inside of master `CollectionViewCell`.

I want user can scrolling through small collectionview which mostly small pieces of images when they try to scroll that small collectionView area, while other scrolling action causing scrolling the master CollectionView.

I believe `UICollectionView` inherited `UIScrollView`, so I don't think I need to add gesture recognizer(panning) in this case. I've test this in two way,

1. touchBegan doesn't detect if I tap on small collectionview area.
2. If I add PanGesture manually to small collectionView and the scrolling in small collectionView doesn't trigger parent collectionView scroll.

Any thought where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe you can implement this method:

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

And to determine whom to give priority in the beginning swipe. And return NO or YES.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. How can I know the gesture recognizer already added for UICollectionViewCell and where should I implement this method?

Comment: You should implement this method in View which contain your main UICollectionView. and UIGestureRecognizer have property view. Use this and  type gestureRocognizer. Somthing like this.